# Carga de caché en LibVLC

Tags: c#

He estado leyendo el siguiente artículo: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/blob/master/docs/best_practices.md

El artículo habla en un punto de crear un archivo de caché para reducir el tiempo de carga con `new LibVLC("--verbose=4", "--reset-plugins-cache");`. La primera vez que cargo el programa, tarda mucho, más que sin este comando, pero se crea en la carpeta plugins de libvlc un archivo `plugins.dat`. Esto se realiza para evitar el tiempo de carga con caché, pero siempre que ejecuto el programa este archivo se actualiza solo (por la fecha de modificación se llega a esta conclusión). Sin embargo, el artículo dice que hay que ejecutar este comando una vez, ¿cómo? La duda que surge es que sin necesidad de crear un plugins.dat o sin utilizar este comando, el programa no tarda en cargarse. ¿Es realmente necesario?

Comment: No deberias preguntarle eso a los que hicieron la libreria? eso parece muy particular para esa libreria...

Comment: ya, no se. ¿Alguna forma de solucionar ese tiempo de carga?

Comment: de que tiempo hablas???

Comment: La primera vez son 20 segundos, luego un segundo. Si reinicio el ordenador tarda otros 20 segundos. Ni idea de como solucionarlo

Comment: Ni idea sin ver tu programa o saber que hace...